# Cannot instantiate Dispatcher from config exception=java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am using Pushlet to push message from server side to web page and get the error mentioned above. Anyone know why this occur?

```
public void run() {
    DataInputStream input;
    try {
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String json = input.readUTF();
        input.close();

        System.out.println("msg from client: " + json);
        String subject = "/pushlet/ping";
        Event event = Event.createDataEvent(subject);
        event.setField("msg", json);
        Dispatcher.getInstance().multicast(event);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Here is the web.xml.

```
<!-- Define the pushlet servlet -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>pushlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>nl.justobjects.pushlet.servlet.Pushlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Define the Servlet Mappings. -->

<!-- The pushlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>pushlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/pushlet.srv</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: @Hiny It says nothing but "Pushlet[FATAL] Cannot instantiate Dispatcher from config exception=java.lang.NullPointerException
"

Comment: Probably `Dispatcher.getInstance()`; look whether all was specified in the config. (I personally cannot help you there.) Show the config in the question.